# Divide Screen into Four Equal Parts using Relative Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I currently have code that allows me to divide the screen into four equal parts, with an image button in each part. However, the code uses linear layouts which brings up the suggestion "nested weights are bad for performance". How can I make my layout using relative layouts?
Below is the code, and here is a picture of the intended format
[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ff191919">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff414141"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Plane"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="airplaneClicked"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff414141"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_brightness"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ff191919">01

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff414141"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sound" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff414141"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/settings2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "How can I make my layout using relative layouts? " -- AFAIK, you can't. Either use the `LinearLayout` approach, or write your own custom `ViewGroup` that implements what you seek.

Comment: Won't linear layouts leave to worse performance?

Comment: "Worse performance" compared to what? Probably it will perform worse than a well-written custom `ViewGroup`. However, writing such a `ViewGroup` is not especially common.

Comment: I just thought that the linear layout was causing my app to use too much memory. I keep on getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in the code above when I use @drawable/ic_brightness on button2 which is a selector with two images. However, if I switch the drawable to a single image, the app runs fine.

Comment: "I just thought that the linear layout was causing my app to use too much memory" -- no. The performance it refers to would be rendering (CPU) performance, not heap space.

Answer (score 1):

Using below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#242425"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#d5d5d5" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#d5d5d5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#d5d5d5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#242425"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#d5d5d5" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to write `orientation="horizontal"` in both `LinearLayout` tag that puts two components in row. Fix it, I'll vote you up

Comment: @Apurva LinearLayouts are horizontal by default. Just FYI.

Comment: @Apurva, as **Mike** mentioned, LinearLayouts are horizontal by default

Comment: @MikeM., I think problem reason was because of bad usage of **layout_weight** in xml file. when we set value for **layout_weight**, we should set **layout_width** or **layout_height** to zero.

Comment: @FarshadKazemi Gotcha. I figure the OP read somewhere that nested LinearLayouts _might_ cause a performance drop in certain cases, and is trying to avoid them at all costs. With the simple layout they've got, there's really no need to worry about it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/i1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/i2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r3" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/i3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/i4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```