# How can i set four picture on different corner on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, image

My problem image https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF5MJ.png

How can I set the layout like this? A,B,C,D means for four picture,they are all same/similar size and the line are nearly on the center.

I use android studio and i found they can only set on center but cannot do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TableLayout` for this task. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html).

Comment: Should be a flag, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

put one main relativeLayout and in one main layout put height and with as Fill_parent and inside main relativlayout Put four relativelayout with property of match_parent in both height and width and place image in a center of each relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below question there you can find your answer :)

[Divide Screen into Four Equal Parts using Relative Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660799/divide-screen-into-four-equal-parts-using-relative-layout)